# wrong module specified in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Visual Studio 2010

I have System.Web.MVC 2 and System.Web.Routing 4 referenced in my project.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

I am getting a following error when specifying a module:

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

> Error:  Wrong module specified. System.Web, version 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Note: i am upgrading Kentico CMS to new version and they are now utilizing routing also. The upgrade document wants to add a module with version 3.5.0.0. Since i have version 4.0 referenced, i cant do 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```